# How to turn off NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4, nszombie, nszombieenabled

I have just migrated to Xcode 4 and i had zombie activated in Xcode 3 for my app. I used the following method:

> Go to Project -> Edit Active Executable
>   Click Arguments
>   Click + in the "Variables to be set in the environment" section
>   Enter NSZombieEnabled in the Name column and YES in the Value column.
>   Make sure the checkmark for the NSZombieEnabled entry is checked.

Now i want to make sure it is off for my application but do not understand how to check/do that in XCODE4, anyone that can share some light on that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To edit environment variables, go to Menu Product / Edit Scheme…, select the desired configuration (you probably want 'Run') from the left sidebar first and then click on the Arguments tab. Environment variables are configurable there.